# Sharepoint 2010 radiobuttons display horizontally

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, schema

Is there a way to get radio buttons to display horizontally in Sharepoint 2010?

Here is the code from my schema but the buttons display vertically.

```
  <Field Name ="Hardware_Type" DisplayName="Hardware Type" Type="Choice" Format="RadioButtons">
    <CHOICES>
      <CHOICE>Smart Phone</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>Cellular Phone</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>Tablet</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>Air Card</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
  </Field>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you would need to do:

Two per row:

```
$().SPServices.SPArrangeChoices({
columnName: "Hardware Type",
perRow: 2
});
```

Seven per row:

```
$().SPServices.SPArrangeChoices({
columnName: "Hardware Type",
perRow: 7
});
```

[Here is a link](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPArrangeChoices&referringTitle=Documentation) with some more info on this.